# Wort für das pingelige Essverhalten meines Sohnes

Tags: single-word-request

Ich stehe gerade auf dem Schlauch und mir fällt momentan kein genauer Begriff ein. Und zwar möchte ich das Essverhalten meines Sohns beschreiben:

Er hat im Urlaub gesehen, wie meine Schwägerin sich reichlich übergeben hat (durch Eigeninitiative), nachdem Sie in ihrem Essen einen »Fremdkörper« gefunden hat. Seitdem ist unser Sohn sehr schwierig, was das Essen betrifft, und es kommt schon mal vor, dass er Essen zurückweist oder ausspuckt, weil er meint, da sei etwas Komisches drin. Zum Beispiel empfindet er kleine Pilze oder Champignons in einer Pilzsuppe als Fremdkörper.

Leider fällt mir dazu nur der norddeutsche Ausdruck *etepetete* ein oder *pingelig,* aber kann man das für ein Essverhalten benutzen?

Comment: Dürften alle regional sein. Persönlich würde ich _schnäkig_ sagen. Anderswo heißt es zum Beispiel _heikel_, wenn ich mich nicht täusche.

Comment: @chirlu dann müsste ich wohl nach einer Bayrischen Version fragen ;)

Comment: In Österreich, in der Umgangssprache: »haklich« (mit langem a gesprochen). Heißt auf Hochdeutsch: »heikel«

Comment: Nicht essenbezogen, aber in dem Kontext auch nciht falsch: Mimosenhaft.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Für dieses Verhalten, das sich natürlich nicht nur an jungen Kindern sondern auch an Erwachsenen beobachten lässt, existieren im deutschen Sprachraum viele Ausdrücke, die der [Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](http://atlas-alltagssprache.de) zu folgender Karte zusammengefasst hat:

[image: Waehlerisch beim Essen]

Als verbreitetste deutsche Variante fällt *mäkelig* ins Auge (grüne Punkte), während insbesondere in Nordrhein-Westfalen fast alle möglichen Ausdrücke vorkommen. Weitergehende Erklärungen finden sich auch auf der [Seite des Atlas](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f09b/):

> Für Personen, die sehr wählerisch sind, wenn es ums Essen geht, gibt es sehr viele Bezeichnungen – geradezu ein Feuerwerk an Varianten. Dennoch lassen sich die Varianten zu folgenden Grundformen zusammenfassen: Südlich von Donau und Thaya sagt man überwiegend heikel (auch in den Formen haklich, haglich oder hoigl). Im Frankenland heißt es gnäschig, in Baden-Württemberg schleckig und in der Schweiz zum Teil gschnädderfräsig. In Norddeutschland, besonders im Nordosten, aber nicht in Schleswig-Holstein (hier sagt man krüsch), hört man überwiegend mäkelig, in Sachsen auch käbsch, in der Pfalz und im Saarland, teilweise auch in Baden-Württemberg, schnäkig. In Ostbelgien und im Mosel-Saar-Gebiet heißt es auch klott, am Mittelrhein schlauchig. In Westdeutschland ist dann kaum noch eine Ordnung zu erkennen, die bunteste Vielfalt findet sich dabei in Nordrhein-Westfalen. Hier nur einige Beispiele: mäkelig, schnücks(ch), pingelig, leksch, schlauchig, wählerisch ... und viele weitere. Zu vielen dieser Ausdrücke gibt es entsprechende Dialektwörter. Deshalb finden sich vor allem in Dialektwörterbüchern Informationen über die Herkunft vieler dieser Ausdrücke, vgl. z.B.: schnäkig (vgl. PfWb, V, Sp. 1219f.: schnäkelig zum Verb schnäken mit der Doppelbedeutung 'wählerisch beim Essen sein' oder auch 'heimlich naschen') klott (vgl. RhWb, II, Sp. 1290: glutt 'wählerisch im Essen') schlauchig (vgl. RhWb, VII, Sp. 1262f., zu schlauchen in der Bedeutung 'etwas Gutes essen, das Beste oben wegessen, naschen u. ä.'. Schlauch (mhd. sluoch) kann nach Kluge (S. 724) auch einen Rüssel bezeichnen, also evtl. eine Anspielung auf die "kritische Nase"?) schnäubisch (vgl. RhWb, VII, Sp. 1560: zum Verb schnauben, verwandt mit schnuppen 'etw. Leckeres essen, naschen'). Zudem besteht wohl eine Verwandtschaft zu den Lexemen schnuppern, schnauben (also das Essen kritisch beschnuppern). Eventuell stellt der Anlaut sch auch eine Lautgebärde für die kritisch hochgezogene Oberlippe des „kritischen Gourmets“ dar (Kluge, S.735). pingelig (vgl. RhWb, VI, Sp. 848: zum Verb pingeln in der Bedeutung 'langsam und ohne Appetit essen') krüsch geht nach Kluge, S. 490, wohl auf das Adjektiv kürisch zum Verb küren (= 'wählen') zurück. Zuerst wurde die Form wohl zu kürsch verkürzt und anschließend die Laute ü und r vertauscht.

Comment: Wahnsinn, versteht man einander da überhaupt noch ;)?

Comment: @MediSaif Solange du *hoakl* sagst, versteh ich dich dabei wunderbar ;)

Comment: Es fällt auf, dass viele dieser Wörter Dialektwörter oder Wörter der Umgangssprache sind. So steht z.B. das in Ost-Österreich und Südbayern verbreitete Wort »haklich«, mir als erstes einfiel als ich die Frage las, weder im ÖWB noch im Duden. Und das zurecht, denn man würde nicht erwarten, dieses Wort in einer Zeitung zu lesen, oder von einem Nachrichtensprecher zu hören. Insofern wäre interessant, eine ähnliche Karte zu sehen, wenn nur standarddeutsche Begriffe erlaubt wären (also Wörter, die auch ein Nachrichtensprechen im Fernsehen verwenden würde).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das widerspricht allerdings der Idee des Atlasses der deutschen *Alltags*sprache, die explizit nach gesprochener Umgangssprache frägt. Allerdings halte ich das Wort *heikel* (das in Süd- und Westbayern wie auch Tirol/Südtirol wesentlich häufiger als *haklich* aufzutreten scheint) auch für ausreichend standardsprachlich – gesprochen wird es ja, bei uns zumindest, *hoakl*.

Comment: Die Zielsetzung des Atlas ist mir schon klar. Trotzdem wäre es interessant zu erfahren, welche standardsprachlichen Wörter die Redakteure von Lokalzeitungen in unterschiedlichen Regionen verwenden würden.

Comment: @Jan: Also "standardsprachlich" ist "heikel" in dieser Bedeutung denke ich nicht. Es mag sein, dass es in mehreren aneinander angrenzenden Dialekten so verwendet wird, aber andererseits bin ich in Südwestdeutschland aufgewachsen und kenne "heikel" ausschließlich als so etwas wie "kritisch", "riskant". Hättest du mir gesagt, dass du beim Essen "heikel" bist, hätte ich vor dem Lesen dieser Frage nicht verstanden, was du meinst.

Comment: Interessant, dass obwohl ich in einer Region wohne, wo so etwa die Hälfte aller Farbpunkte auf dieser Karte vorhanden sind, kommt mir nur "pingelig" und "wählerisch" geläufig vor. Wobei beide Wörter eine unterschiedliche Konnotation haben und je nach tatsächlicher Aussage würde ich zum Einen oder Anderen greifen.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Da fände ich berichtenswert, an welchen Nachrichtentext im Besonderen du dabei gedacht hättest ;) - mir selbst will da nichts Rechtes einfallen. Mir will scheinen, dass bestimmte Sachverhalte in Standardsprache entweder gar nicht oder nur so verdeckt angesprochen werden können, dass nur geübte Dekodierer von Diplomatensprech und ähnlichen Codes die im Grunde gemeinte unverblümte Aussageabsicht verstehen.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Ich habe dabei an keinen konkreten Nachrichtentext gedacht, sondern habe in meinem Kommentar versucht den Unterschied zwischen Standardsprache und Umgangssprache festzumachen. Das, was Nachrichtensprecher sagen, das was in Zeitungen gedruckt wird, und das, was in offiziellen Aussendungen von Behörden steht, ist Standarddeutsch (wörtliche Zitate sind natürlich ausgenommen). Begriffe, die von den diesen Redaktionen nicht geduldet werden, sind umgangssprachlich, gehören einem Dialekt an, oder sind vulgär (wobei vulgäre Ausdrücke durchaus auch standarddeutsch sein können).

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Beispielsweise ist das Wort *»Sackerl«* (überall sonst: *»Tüte«*) in Österreich Teil der Standardsprache: [Plastiksackerl-Verbot](https://www.bmnt.gv.at/umwelt/abfall-ressourcen/Plastiksackerl-Verbot.html). Das Verb *»parkieren«* (sonst: *»parken«*) ist hingegen Teil des Schweizer Standards: [Parkieren in der blauen Zone](https://www.srf.ch/sendungen/ratgeber/parkieren-in-der-blauen-zone-so-geht-s-richtig) und die *»Schippe«* (sonst: *»Schaufel«*) findet nur in einigen deutschen Bundesländern (z.B. Reinland-Pfalz, Hessen, Brandenburg) den Weg in die Nachrichten:

Comment: (Fortsetzung): [Statt der Prise eine Schippe](https://www.swrfernsehen.de/die-swr-reportage/Statt-der-Prise-eine-Schippe-Ein-Tag-in-der-Mensakueche-Trier,av-o1119911-100.html)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ja, der Unterschied zwischen Standard- und Umgangssprache ist schwer zu bestimmen. Nach deinem Definitionsversuch wäre ein Spiegel-Artikel, weil gedruckt, standardsprachlich, aber Journalisten auch der sog. Qualitätsmedien versuchen heutzutage, lebendig und interessant zu schreiben, und dabei werden nach meiner Beobachtung recht häufig umgangssprachliche Register gezogen. Behördenverlautbarungen oder z.B. auch AGBs sind ziemlich oft in einem verquasten, juristisch abgesicherten Kauderwelsch verfasst, für das man Übersetzungshilfen braucht. Eine Grenzziehung bleibt schwierig.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ja, es gibt verschiedene regionale Standards. ('_Tüte_' heißt übrigens auf schwäbisch '_Gugg_'). Und was die '_Schippe_' angeht: Wohl niemand sagt '_jemanden auf die Schaufel nehmen_' - aber das nur zur Auflockerung. Im Grundsatz sehe ich das wie du, nur: Eine gute Abgrenzung zwischen sog. Standardsprache und sog. Umgangssprache habe ich bis jetzt nicht gefunden. Weitaus tragfähiger dürfte die Unterscheidung _gesprochene / geschriebene Sprache_ sein, und in der gesprochenen herrschen da sehr verschiedene regionale Substandards.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Du hast geschrieben: *»Wohl niemand sagt 'jemanden auf die Schaufel nehmen'«.* Millionen Österreich tun das sehr wohl: [Kühbauer nimmt Schützling Dibon auf die Schaufel](https://www.krone.at/1903281), [Kabarettisten-Duo nimmt sich selbst auf die Schaufel.](https://www.meinbezirk.at/voelkermarkt/c-lokales/auf-der-schaufel_a275855), [Bagger-Boys nehmen Kurz und Kickl auf die Schaufel](https://www.wannundwo.at/sound/2019/02/05/bagger-boys-nehmen-kurz-und-kickl-auf-die-schaufel.wawo)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Echt jetzt? Sachen gibt's, die gibt's gar nicht. Aber gut zu wissen. Kennt man in Österreich auch 'auf die Schippe nehmen'? In Deutschland würde dasselbe mit 'Schaufel' wohl als falsch empfunden, zumindest von mir (Ruhrgebiet).

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Die *Schippe* ist ein typischer Teutonismus. Wir Österreicher kennen das Wort zwar, weil jeder Österreich auch deutsches Deutsch versteht (90% aller monatlich erscheinenden Magazine werden aus Deutschland importiert, ca. 99% aller in Österreich verkauften Bücher sind in deutschem Deutsch verfasst, und jeder der Kabel- oder Satellitenfernsehen hat, hört täglich deutsches Deutsch aus dem Fernseher.) Aber wir sprechen trotzdem unsere Muttersprache, und die ist österreichisches Deutsch. *»Schippe«* ist aber kein Vokabel dieser Sprache, daher wird dieses Wort nicht aktiv verwendet.

Answer (score 5):

Pingelig im Kontext von Essverhalten wäre meiner Meinung nach **mäkelig**.

Wie *wählerisch*, aber mit negativer Konnotation: *übertrieben, unbegründet*.

Comment: wählerisch finde ich gar nicht so schlecht, aber war wohl zu einfach, als dass es mir spontan einfallen würde ;)

Comment: Ich verwende wählerisch, pingelig und mäkelig, beziehe aber die letzten beiden selten aufs Essen

Comment: @Ludi Interessant! Wofür verwendest Du _mäkelig_?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Im Freundinnen meiner Mutter zu beschreiben, welche die Kunst alles und jedes zu bemäkeln perfektioniert haben. Dabei mag ich sehr von "Standard" abweichen.

Answer (score 2):

Umgangssprachlich „**etepetete** (sein)“

> Adj. etepetete

Etepetete sein ist eine umgangssprachlich verwendete Redewendung, die besonders im nördlichen Teil des deutschen Sprachraumes, vor allem in Berlin, bekannt ist und eine Person beschreibt, die im Standarddeutsch beschrieben eingebildet und geziert erscheint.

Wenn eine Person etepetete ist bzw. sich etepetete benimmt, ist darüber hinaus ein verweichlichtes, verwöhntes, umständliches, überfeines, zimperliches und penibles Verhalten gemeint. Beschrieben wird eine Person, die gerne besonders vornehm wirken will, es aber gar nicht ist.<sup>1</sup>

**Quellen:**

<sup>1</sup>: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etepetete

Comment: Den kenne ich natürlich auch.

Answer (score 0):

Die bisher vorgeschlagenen Begriffe wie "pingelig" oder "mäkelig" passen für mein Empfinden nicht gut. Pingelig oder mäkelig wäre es, wenn die betroffene Person besonders hohe Ansprüche an die Qualität einer Speise hätte und bei kleinsten Abweichungen davon in sozial unangenehmer Weise Kritik daran äußerte.

Der beschriebene Fall des Sohnes scheint mir etwas anderes zu sein. Es geht nicht um die Enttäuschung - zwar hochgestochener - Erwartungen an die Qualität eines Produkts (hier: einer Speise), sondern vielmehr hat der Sohn ein Verhalten gesehen, das ihn in irgend einer Weise beeindruckt hat (möglicherweise durch die der Tante in der Folge zuteilgewordene Zuwendung durch andere Familienmitglieder) und das er darum nun repliziert mit der Erwartung eines ähnlichen sozialen Profits für ihn selbst. Dabei nimmt er, wie in der Frage beschrieben, jegliche zufällig sichtbare Eigenschaft (falsch als "Fremdkörper" deklarierte Bestandteile) einer Speise zum Anlass. Das ist nicht pingelig, mäkelig oder etepetete, auch nicht heikel (wie das in der Landkarte erwähnte "hoakl" im Standarddeutschen heißt), denn heikel wäre *übervorsichtig*.

Der Sohn instrumentalisiert vielmehr die Situation, um Aufmerksamkeit zu erlangen.

Ich habe überlegt, ob man dies

> zwanghaft

nennen könnte, aber das trifft nicht recht, denn es ist kaum ein innerer Zwang, der ihn dazu treibt sondern eher eben die Aussicht auf besondere Aufmerksamkeit. Wir kommen damit in die Nähe von

> verzogen

oder noch eher vielleicht von

> manipulativ

Comment: Meinem Verständnis nach geht diese Antwort ein wenig an der Frage vorbei, da konkret nach einer Bezeichnung für das Essverhalten selber gefragt war, nicht für die Kombination aus Essverhalten und Nachahmung desselben. Das heißt, ich gehe davon aus, dass ebenso nach einer Bezeichnung für das Essverhalten der Schwägerin gesucht wurde.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ja dass ist in erster Linie was gemeint war! Daher finde ich die angegebenen Vorschläge etwas abwägig.

Answer (score -1):

Bei diesem Verhalten handelt es sich - das sehe ich ähnlich wie Christian Geiselmann - um ein Psychospiel. Man könnte es 'Prinzessin auf der Erbse' nennen. Initiiert wurde es im konkreten FAll durch das für mich leicht hysterisch dargestellte Verhalten der Schwägerin ('durch Eigeninitiative': standardsprachlich, gemeint ist wohl: Sie hat sich den Finger in den Hals gesteckt - Was wird sie da wohl verschluckt gehabt haben?) Der Sohnemann hat sich das abgekuckt und tut das, was viele Kinder phasenweise tun: Sobald das Essen auf dem Teller ist, fängt er an zu 'sortieren' und schiebt ihm verdächtige Objekte auf den Tellerrand.

Entgegen dem Sprachempfinden von Christian Geiselmann wird ein solches Verhalten in weiten Teilen unseres Sprachraums 'mäkelig' genannt. Leider lässt sich aber nicht herausfinden, welcher Impuls den Befragten (beim AdA handelt es sich um Fragebogen-'Kampagnen') vorgelegt wurde, um ihre Version für 'wählerisch beim Essen' zu liefern. Oft sind das typische Sätze im Lückentext-Format, in denen das zu erfragende Wort einzusetzen ist. Ein paar der gelieferten Varianten kenne ich, so dass ich vermute, dass der Impuls die anvisierte Bedeutung recht gut getroffen hat. Die Befragten hatten alle denselben Fragebogen, und sowohl 'mäkelig' als auch 'pingelig' wurden genannt.

Wohl keiner benutzt derartige Wörter unterschiedslos. Die mir bekannten aus der Galerie haben für mich verschiedene Bedeutungen: 'wählerisch' geht in Richtung 'anspruchsvoll', 'pingelig' tendiert nach 'akribisch-kleinkariert', 'verschnuppt' sehe ich eher als 'naschhaft' bzw. 'zuckersüchtig', 'heikel' als 'sensibelchenhaft'. 'Etepetete' ist für mich ein wenig 'ehrpusselig' und darauf bedacht, das kein Außenstehender etwas zum Herumkritisieren findet. Das wird bei anderen anders sein. Wenn man es genauer wissen will, bleibt außer den Wörterbüchern, die nicht alle Nuancen erfassen können, nur die eigene Recherche in den Korpora von https://www.dwds.de/ oder in http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/de, oder man schickt eine eigene Google-Suche los oder schaut etwa bei https://www.dict.cc/?s=picky+eating nach.

Rosinenpickerei beim Essen wird in der dritten Person (*unser Töchterchen ist neuerdings beim Essen ...*) ziemlich sicher so bezeichnet, wie auf der Deutschlandkarte vom AdA wiedergegeben. Der erste Satz, der **mir** allerdings einfiel, war 'Hör auf zu sortieren!' So versuchten unsere Eltern am Essenstisch, irgendwelche Eigenwilligkeiten und Marotten von uns Kindern beim Essen im Keim zu ersticken. Leider gingen sie dabei nicht gerade zimperlich vor, aber solche Schnurren wie 'Gemüse ess ich nicht' hätte es bei uns nicht gegeben - dann eben ohne Essen ins Bett, und Taschengeld, um sich selbst was zu kaufen gab's nicht.

Fazit: Als Essverhalten so, wie im AdA genannt, als 'Psychospiel' gibt's sicherlich, auch je nach Perspektive, eine reichhaltige Auswahl (Essenskapriolen, Grillen, Eigensinnigkeiten, Machtkampf, Selbstbehauptungstraining, prinzessinnenhaftes Gebaren usw.)